# Angular mock socket service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, stub

I've got a `socketService` which is being used while component initialized to get some data from a server. However, I cannot mock it because it says

> TypeError: this.socketService.send is not a function

```
export class SocketStub {
    send(message: ISocketRequest): Observable<any> {
        return of({"status": 200, "data": "success"});
    }
}
```

Providers in test

```
providers: [{
    provide: SocketService,
    useValue: SocketStub
}]
```

And beforeEach

```
beforeEach(() => {
        socketService = TestBed.get(SocketService);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersItemComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

The one test I'm trying to run is a default test 'should create'. Since component uses this `socketService` to get the data I need to mock it, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try using [`useClass`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#defining-providers) rather than `useValue` when providing the stub service.

Answer (score 0):

Use **useClass**. It works for me when using `ngx-socket-io`

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ...
       providers: [{ provide: SocketService, useClass: SocketStub }],
    //...
})
```